# Does this basis have a name?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, reference-request, change-of-basis, change-of-variable

When dealing with multi-dimensional integrations such as:

$$\int f\left(\sum_i x_i\right) \exp\left(\sum_i x_i^2 \right) d\vec x$$

where $f$ is a scalar function, I often find it helpful to make a change of variables using the basis:

$$u_1=(+1,+1,+1,...,+1) / \sqrt n$$
$$u_2=(+1,-1, 0,..., 0) / \sqrt 2$$
$$u_3=(+1, 0,-1,..., 0) / \sqrt 2$$
$$...$$
$$u_n=(+1, 0, 0,...,-1) / \sqrt 2$$

where $n$ is the dimension. After making a change of variables $\vec x\rightarrow \vec y$ using this basis, the above integral becomes:

$$\int f(\sqrt n y_1) \exp\left(\sum_i y_i^2\right) d\vec y$$

which can be better, because now the integrand factorizes over the $y_i$. Note that here the variable $y_1=\sum x_i\sqrt n$ is the one that does the trick, while the other basis vectors just have to be orthogonal to $u_1$ so that the Jacobian stays at 1.

I do this so often that it gets tiresome having to spell out the new basis. Is there name one can use for this kind of change of variables?

Comment: Not sure if there is a name for this basis, but if you use $u_2 = (+1, -1, 0, 0, \ldots, 0)/\sqrt{2}$, $u_3 = (0, 1, -1, 0, \ldots, 0)/\sqrt{2}$, $u_4 = (0, 0, 1, -1, \ldots, 0)/\sqrt{2}$, etc. instead, they are the normalized [simple roots of type A](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_system#An).

Comment: But that might be a bit of a distraction.  No need to give them a special name, really, other than $u_i$.

Comment: Yes, but without a special name I have to define $u_i$ everytime I use them.

Comment: The "simple roots of type A" is close, but doesn't include $u_1=(1,1,1,...,1)$, which is important for my purpose.

Comment: I thought this would be more commonly used and had a label, or a recognized trick name. Just something I can refer to avoid having to define $u_i$ each time.

Comment: Yes, I meant "the simple roots of type A along with your $u_1$".  If there is a name for this particular basis, it's probably not so commonly known that you can refer to the name without defining it at all.  Better just to define it explicitly.  You don't have to define it *every* time you use it, just define it once.

Comment: Yes, but I still have to define it *every* time I use it in a new paper / note / blog or whatever.